# SOLVED: Yaw Drift with UM7

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

I am experiencing a vexing issue in that using the UM7 ROS driver, after a few minutes (~2)  of running the yaw drifts at a seeming constant rate (I don't have enough points to upload an image to illustrate).  I can use the reset service of the UM7 driver to reset the EKF, but then after awhile (~ 2 min) it starts to drift again.

The odd thing is that this seems to be a problem that is something to do with ROS UM7 driver.  I can use the CH Windows interface and I don't see the issue - i.e, the yaw output is stable.

I am using Firmware U71D.
I have calibrated the mag. with the CH Windows serial interface.
I have experimented with different settings as suggested here: http://www.chrobotics.com/forums/topic/yaw-drift-with-u71d
I have looked through the UM7 driver source code, but can't seem to find anything that would cause this.
I have used the verified that the mag. updates are being used by the unit
I have made sure to "flash commit" the configuration to the UM7 so that it is non-volatile.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.
Brian

---

**SOLUTION**

As Stefan suggested, installing the U71C firmware seemed to fix the issue.  Thank you!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/242129/solved:-yaw-drift-with-um7/) by [BSBingham](https://answers.ros.org/users/26118/bsbingham/) on ROS Answers with karma: 108 on 2016-08-21

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2016-08-22**:
I've given you some karma, so you should be able to upload images now.

**Comment by [xlightx](https://answers.ros.org/users/27611/xlightx/) on 2018-08-02**:
My firmware version of this sensor is U72A and still has the drift. I can't find the older drivers anywhere. Does anyone have them by chance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I also saw extreme yaw drift on a new UM7 unit. It turned out that the estimation of gyro biases that was added in firmware U71D is good in theory, but apparently not very robust in actual use. I downgraded our sensor to firmware U71C and it now works fine again (after trying to make the sensor work with various settings on the newer firmware). I thus recommend downgrading and seeing if it fixes your issue.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2016-08-22

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [BSBingham](https://answers.ros.org/users/26118/bsbingham/) on 2016-08-22**:
Thanks Stefan!

**Comment by [Airuno2L](https://answers.ros.org/users/458/airuno2l/) on 2016-08-23**:
If that solves the problem please click the check mark next to the answer to mark it as solved.